# Exit D Program in Static Constructor

Tags: d, exit, static-constructor

I have a static constructor like this:

```
File errorLog;
static this() {
    try {
        errorLog = File("./log/log.txt", "w");
    } catch(Throwable ex) {
        // STOP PROGRAM EXECUTION
    }
}
```

How would I stop the program execution when the opening of the file fails?

Comment: Not an expert in any sense of the word, but how about just `import core.stdc.stdlib;` and use `exit(-1);`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson That won't destroy the D runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use core.runtime to terminate druntime
http://dlang.org/phobos/core_runtime.html#.Runtime.terminate and exit from core.stdc.stdlib

Comment: Note that this will *not* run destructors on things you've created, like structs sitting on the stack.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe Is there a proper way to do that? The program should  just exit as if the main function returned.

Comment: not really, the best you can do is throw an exception and let it unwind the stack.

Comment: Probably it is better to even throw `Error` here to indicate termination intention.